# Creating a PHP Page to Search a CSV

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV that is appended every 10 minutes with Data that looks similar to

```
07-01-2020 10:40 https://www.google.com OK 0.080382
07-01-2020 10:40 https://www.yahoo.com OK 0.120117
```

The first column being date shown as ***07-01-2020*** in this example,
time represented by the ***10:40***, Link represented by ***https://www.google.com***, Status represented by **OK** and latency represented by **0.080382**

I currently have all the results being displayed with the following bit of code:

```
<?php
$file = fopen("resultsTime.csv", "r");

//Output lines until EOF is reached
while(! feof($file)) {
  $line = fgets($file);
  echo $line. "<br>";
}

fclose($file);
?>
```

This works perfectly fine as it should. However I am looking to instead enter say https://www.google.com into a text box and get the history for that site. An additional piece for that would be I only want when the status is not OK.

Hopefully that is well enough explained. I have seen some examples on here but none that offer enough detail to be able to create my own.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you want to be able to filter the rows of the CSV to only return which rows container a given URL or a given status?

Comment: so you want to filter results for specific url with status not ok?

Comment: You'll have to parse the `$line` so you can filter your results. It looks like a single space is your delimiter.

Comment: This is quite broad, as it means you will have to create an HTML page, do some programming to get data into your PHP (sanitise it!), and then use that data to filter and display the CSV data. There are several methods to do this (parse, grep, put it in a database, to name a few). Perhaps you should start at the beginning and running a PHP tutorial first, as many concepts are trivial and well explained in a good tutorial.

Comment: OP should start with the parsing (since its simply space delimited) and build up from there. But i tend to agree that the implementation (in the end) could be broad @BartFriederichs

Comment: So I'll explain in almost an SQL sense. Basically I want a text box where the user enters a URL, when they hit search they receive a list that shows all dates and times where the given url has a status of != OK i.e. 403 or otherwise. The only thing I am worried about would be when my script is unable to connect to the sites as it runs every 10 minutes and each site in my list only goes down about once a week.

Comment: The deliminator can easily be adjusted if that makes things easier as well

Comment: If you're familiar with SQL why not use DB? Your going to run into issues with this approach sooner than a DB approach.

Comment: @user3783243 wanted a total history rather than a short list and felt having my script append a CSV would be the best approach to that. I'm not sure how exactly to do it in a DB in its current state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indents are a little messy here but this is the solution I came up with that works great.
Should be easily modifiable if others are looking to do the same

```
<center>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label>Site</label><input type="text" name="search">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
        </form>
    </center>

    <center>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $word = $_POST['search'];
    print "<tr><td><u>Date</u><td><u>Time</u></td><td><u>Site</u></td><td><u>Status</u></td><td><u>Latencey</u></td></tr>";
    if (($h = fopen("resultsTime.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        // Convert each line into the local $data variable
        while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            foreach ($data as $str) {
                $site = explode(" ", $str);
                if ($site[3] != "OK" && $site[2] == $word) {
            print "<tr><td>" . $site[0] . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $site[1] . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $site[2] . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $site[3] . "</td>";
            print "<td>" . $site[4] . "</td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }

        // Close the file
        fclose($h);
    }
}
?>
```